# How to add child field to ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'll try to describe the problem as much fast.
I have 2 models:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
class ChildModel(models.Model):
    pid = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'[0-9]{10}', 'invalid number',)],)
```

I'm trying to create CreateView with ModelForm:

```
class NewBranchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    super(NewBranchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = ParentModel
        fields = ['name', 'surname']
     def save(self):
         ...
```

How can i put to template fields for phone from ChildModel, if my template looks so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}<br>
<input type="submit" value="Create new branch" />
```

Thanks and sorry for my English, it's not my native language

Comment: You need to create another form and pass it to template.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [ModelFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) for the phones.